# How do I enforce injecting a specific instance, without access to the class impl code?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to bind a class C from a third-party's package. 
It injects a class Foo instance via constructor -

```
class C {
    public C(@Inject Foo foo) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In my application, I've two instances of Foo bound -

```
bind(Foo.class)
    .to(FooImpl1.class);

bind(Foo.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("SpecialFoo"))
    .to(FooImpl2.class);
```

when C is bound, I want the Named Foo instance to be used. However I do not have access to the code in which C is defined, to be able to put any annotations.

Is there a suggested way of doing that, short of writing my own provider method for C?

Comment: Generally DI frameworks have binding option to a constant / specific object, which shall be used for your requirement. Like Ninject offers `ToConstant` binding

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [PrivateModule](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html). In your example, it will be something like:

```java
public class CModule extends PrivateModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl2.class);
        bind(C.class);
        expose(C.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work unless the other instance of Foo is also in a private module. without that loading this module causes a conflict

Comment: I'd just put FooImpl1 binding in a prvt mod too & that'd work. But that impl is used by many classes, bound in different modules, so converting that to a private module means I need to move all those classes to a single prvt mod & expose them for use in my app - which is fine.. but i think writing a provider for C then is quicker

Comment: You can have other dependencies as separate modules and install them inside the private module if the code duplication is a concern here.
But yeah, I'd also be like to be pragmatic. If C is always going to be taking one-argument constructor, then writing a provider might be the way to go